# how does navigation drawer cover actionbar?

Tags: android, css, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want to make to cover action bar when navigation drawer appears.
but i know only to stay action bar when navigation drawer appears.(and i know that this is standard form at google)
i didn’t find stackoverflow perfectly, because I cannot speak english well.
Now i made (picture 1)form, How do i want to make to cover action bar when navigation drawer appears as (pic2) form?

pic 1 : https://imageshack.com/i/ex3qfeOIp

pic 2: https://imageshack.com/i/p88OOwyTp

Comment: You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174941/3913366 .

Answer (score -2):

Its kind of easy.First u need to add listener to your navigation drawer `setDrawerListener` in that u make a listener of `DrawerListener` class. This class has methods `onDrawerClosed()` and `onDrawerOpened()`. In these methods u can hide the action bar or choose to show the action bar appropriately using `getActionBar().hide()` or `getActionBar().show()`

Comment: I don't think that's what @Mhwan asked. The idea is to ver the action bar, not to hide it. Besides, hiding the action causes a full redraw of the layout.

Comment: Please refer to images for what has been asked

Comment: please make me understand what he really wants, as per the image he completely hid the action bar and displayed the navigation panel