# Android action navigation Drawer overlay action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I have implemented navigation drawer in my application. I want this navigation drawer to display just like google play i.e it will overlay action bar. I googled it but have not find any perfect solution. Since I already implemented a navigation drawer so I don't want to implement overlay-ed android navigation drawer. Is there any way I can turn my navigation drawer into an overlay-ed one. I was trying to change application theme to no action bar in my `onDeawerOpen()` , but it was not work for me. Any body have any simple idea for this. Or I have to implement a overlay-ed navigation drawer? Here is the code of my `MainClass`.

```
public class Activity_Home extends Activity {
    private String[] titles;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ArrayList<Model_Drawer_Items> drawerItems;
    private TypedArray drawerIcons;
    Adpater_DrawerAdapter drawerAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
        setupDrawer();
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.back, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name

        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //  setTheme(R.style.noActionBarTheme);

            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity__main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        // }
    }

    public void setupDrawer() {
        try {
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

            View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
            drawerList.addHeaderView(header);
            drawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_iconos);
            titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_options);
            drawerItems = new ArrayList<Model_Drawer_Items>();
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[0], drawerIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[1], drawerIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[2], drawerIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[3], drawerIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[4], drawerIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[5], drawerIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[6], drawerIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[7], drawerIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[8], drawerIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[9], drawerIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
            drawerItems.add(new Model_Drawer_Items(titles[10], drawerIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
            drawerAdapter = new Adpater_DrawerAdapter(this, drawerItems);
            drawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }

        private void selectItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My drawer is working perfectly. Just want an overlay-ed one.Thanks in advance. And one more thing. Does overlay-ed drawer worked only on 4.0 and above?

Comment: Some one already asked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294954/android-navigation-drawer-on-top-actionbar

Comment: Tried it. But have not worked for me.

Comment: Used it in a couple of my projects and it works fine just make sure you are doing it right ;)

Comment: just simply hide your default action bar and create custom action bar and set left top button for open a drawer and set mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START); on click on button.

Comment: Try theme compat and extending from AppCompatActivity